# Android Studio logcat search bar

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

We are a group of developers, we ALL have the latest studio but some of us has a logcat search bar that can be triggered by Command + F like this:
[image]

And some of use cannot trigger that search bar... any idea what is the difference??

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the `Keymap` (`Settings -> Keymap`) of Android Studio has been changed to `Eclipse` (Or something else) from `Default`. Then `Apply` the changes. PFB the image FYR.

[image]

Change it back to `Default` and try hitting `Ctrl+F` to get the search bar be visible again.

Hope this helps.

Note: Later you can change it back to your favorite keymap.

Comment: This is not the case, ⌘ + F is the search short key on my keymap.. same as everyone else at the office

Comment: it is a shame I didn't have this in the screenshot but they also have an icon on the left side which I don't have.. some of the logcat UI component look entirely different